# Regular expression to extract lyrics

Tags: javascript, regex

`'[03:22.00][03:55.00]Rain on me, rain, rain'`
I want to get the lyrics through regular expressions,I tried to get the characters after "]", but this is not correct.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I try `str.match(/(?<=\])(.*)/)`,but this is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regular expression should capture everything between the last closing bracket and the end of the string:

`/([^\]]+$)/`

`'[03:55.00][05:44.22]Rain on me, rain, rain'.match(/([^\]]+$)/)`

Comment: I try `'[03:55.00][05:44.22]Rain on me, rain, rain'.match(/([^]]+$)/)`,Doesn't seem to get the correct result

Comment: Ah, my bad, I forgot to escape the bracket in the regex. I just edited the answer. Try that and let me know how it goes.

Comment: You're welcome! It looks like you are new to the site. There's no obligation, but if a response answers your question, you can click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it as the correct answer. This will help future users identify that a solution has been found. Enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

Replace is better here:

```
'[03:22.00][03:55.00]Rain on me, rain, rain'.replace(/.*\]/, '')
```